# An exception is thrown if read string from remote url in Xamarin Forms C# with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I met a strange exception while I tried to get data from remote url:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new AndroidClientHandler());
string response = client.GetStringAsync( "url" ).Result;
```

and I got an exception like:

`Unable to convert instance of type 'Java.Net.URLConnectionInvoker' to type 'Java.Net.HttpURLConnection'.`

I tried to get string by link `https://www.pricy.ro/product/pachet-a--suport-tv-23--42----kit-curatare---cablu-hdmi-1-4--3m-582813c69d126a2d3cba8f5c/` (where error occur) but for other link, seems work: `https://www.pricy.ro/product/navigatie-gps-serioux-urban-pilot-upq700-7-inchi-5788d87e9d126a5cacfac2bc/`

I don't know why.

And the stack trace:

[image]

Comment: that's rather strange! Can you post the complete stacktrace, please?

Comment: I updated the stack trace with a picture

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above issue by using:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
```

instead of

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new AndroidClientHandler());
```

For the first line of code, install [ModernHttpClient](https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient) from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient/).

Answer (score 0):

Switching to ModernHttpClient is not the right thing to do, since it is superseded by Xamarin's own native HTTP handlers.

For me, the underlying cause was a URL that included two whacks in the wrong spot, like `http://example.com//api/v1/foo`. This can easily happen if you're concatenating strings to construct your URI.